# In Oracle, is there a query to find whether a function exists?

Tags: sql, sqlplus

Suppose that I want to find out whether a function called `PERIOD_DIFF` exists in Oracle SQL.

Is there a way to do so via SQL*Plus , running a query ?

Comment: Try to call it.  If you fail, read the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try one of these. `user_source` `dba_source` `all_source`

For example if you have access to dba_source, you can try something like this

```
 SELECT name from dba_source where type = 'FUNCTION' AND name LIKE '%PERIOD_DIFF%'/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:
Select owner, object_name from all_objects 
where object_type = 'FUNCTION' and object_name = 'PERIOD_DIFF'